# Any module is support npx like argv parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, yargs

Any module is support `npx` like argv parser?

i write a module `ynpx`
https://github.com/bluelovers/ws-ypx/tree/master/packages/ypx

but i can't found a safe way make input cli argv parse like npx do

```
ynpx -p xxx yyy -p
```

what i expected is

all argv befroe `yyy` is parse like normally argv parser do

but after `yyy` will not parse and keep as source input order

Comment: You could look into the npx source and see what they use.

Comment: Can you clarify you question for me? Do you want to support cli args like `<command> -p foo -p bar`?

Comment: @Evert they are make it for npx only, i don't wanna make a new module for ynpx parse only

Comment: @JohnnyZabala i update desc